# Is there a word for a road/path that splits specifically into three directions?

Tags: single-word-requests

According to [Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fork) and [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fork?s=t), one of the definitions of a fork is the something that divides into two or more branches.

Wiktionary.org provides an alternative definition that is more specific:

> "An intersection in a road or path where one road is split into two."

Is there a word that specifically means: an intersection in a road or path where one road is split into three?  I thought of *trifurcation* but am trying to find something more specific to a road or path.

An example sentence would be:

> "Turn left at the *trifurcation* in the road."

Comment: If a bifurcation in the road is a *fork*, then perhaps a trifurcation is a *trident*? Otherwise I think it's just generically an *intersection* (specifically a *four-way intersection*, counting the 3 road trifurcation and the road leading up to it).

Comment: In the special case that the angle between the roads is a right angle,  it'd just be called a crossroads.

Comment: @DougWarren I am trying to describe something that trifurcates in a shape somewhat resembling a trident.  Intersection feels less specific that trifurcation in this case, but still correct.

Comment: Literally a trident?  One road where the handle is, turning into three, which terminate/begin at the handle-end?

Comment: And is it your intention to be understood?

Comment: @TimRomano I am envisioning the left and right "prongs" branching off into their own directions in a diagonal course.  My intention is to be descriptive.

Comment: It is unclear at this point whether you are in need of a word that describes the shape of the three roads or the process of tripartition. Would you please clear it up.

Comment: @vickyace I am looking for a word that describes a road that trifurcates in the following directions: (1) straight ahead, (2) at a somewhat 45 degree angle to the left, and (3) at a somewhat 45 degree angle to the right.  A trifurcation, intersection, tridental or quadrivial road are accepted descriptions.  I am searching for any other words that may further describe the aforementioned road.

Comment: @Amaziah trisection? Perhaps, trichotomous

Comment: @NVZ Perhaps.  At this point, I think a tridental may be the best description I am looking for.

Comment: I would say "forks into three branches."   Look at an actual fork: it has four tines.  Old forks had three tines.  People will understand.

Comment: And a fork in the road is a "*furcation*", no matter how many "*furcs*" it has. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a term in formal garden design to describe a location where paths split into three (or four or five) which in English is called a Goose-foot and in French a '[Patte d'Oie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patte_d%27Oie)'.
The Wiki Link specifically talks about French garden design, but Goose-foot was used both as a term and a feature in Stuart period gardens in the UK.
Be aware though that it is by no means a term in common modern usage outside of landscape professionals (and even we don't use it often.)

Comment: According to [the Wikipedia article you reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patte_d%27oie), 'The French term patte d'oie (literally "goose foot", in English sometimes referred to as a "crow's foot"[1]) describes a design whereby three, four, or five or more straight roads or paths radiate out from a central point', so not specific to 3 'on-routes' (ie a 4-node).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure of your point. My answer in 2016 noted that the split could be up to five way. The term isn't a perfect mapping to the OPs desired use, but that was made clear six years ago. Note the 'or more' part of your quote from Wiki only dates from 2018, two years after my answer linked the page.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. It's always best to paste an extract, as these things do change (as does usage). I'll get rid of the downvote. // 'Three-way fork' is perhaps closest.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***[three-way fork](https://www.google.fr/search?q=four+way+definition&biw=532&bih=349&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit0NTHs77MAhWBwBQKHSugBH4Q_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=%22three+way+fork%22)***

> three-way
>
> *adj.* Having, permitting, or indicating passage in three directions: *a three-way intersection*.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/three-way)
>
> *"Turn left at the [three-way fork](http://nickandzuzu.com/2015/01/fork-in-the-road/) in the road."*

Answer (score 0):

We have a lot of angle streets in Chicago. Here, these intersections where 3 streets meet at a point are known as **five-way** or **six-way intersections** (if one of the streets dead-ends).

Coming to an intersection of such, one would take a *hard left* or *soft left*. I know of no other terminology, but I like the answer given elsewhere of *trifurcates.*

Answer (score 0):

A **crossroads** is the term I’m familiar with:

> a place where two roads meet and cross each other
> — [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/crossroads)

Comment: Hello, Rose. This wouldn't be used where the angular spread of the 3 ongoing paths is say 50°, and this is more the situation I think OP envisions. Also, the special case has already been mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Try [quadrivial](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quadrivial) at collins and [quadrivial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadrivial) at Merriam Webster.

It should satisfy.

Comment: Thank you @vickyace. This is more specific than an *intersection* but does not seem to describe *this* situation better than a trifurcation.

Answer (score -2):

perhaps "trivium" (Latin)-it's the root of the term "trivial" :)

Comment: *Trivium* is a real word meaning "an introductory curriculum at a medieval university involving the study of grammar, rhetoric, and logic." (NOAD).